# Customized quick replies using Node.js Webook in Dialogflow v2

Tags: javascript, node.js, webhooks, dialogflow-es, chatbot

### My Use case to better understand the question

I'm developing a chatbot to provide support to workers in solving problems in a hypothetic assembly line.  After the bot greets the user, it advices him to identify himself with his badge number. Then, if the user accepts the bot's prompt, the bot asks for which component in a list he needs support.
Every worker can manage only a subset of set of the assembly line components.
My goal is to show to the user only the parts he is qualified to manage.[image]

### ...but the real problem is here

My question is about setting Quick Replies via  Node.js webhook. Here you can see

#### My webhook using QuickReplies(simplified)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {QuickReplies}= require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const https=require('https');


exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

 function getAllowedParts(agent){
      /* deleted all unuseful details*/
      agent.add(new QuickReplies(['A','B','C']);
  }  //close getAllowedParts


  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('UserIntro', getAllowedParts);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);

});
```

but it doesn't work, printing in console

> TypeError: QuickReplies is not a constructor

I followed what I found [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/pull/103) and I used the WebhookClient functions at https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/docs/WebhookClient.md#WebhookClient+handleRequest.

The true problem is that I can't understand what is the correct procedure to add non-default quick replies using Node.js webhook in Dialogflow v2 .
I also looked to the [rich messages documentantion](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/rich-messages#quick_replies), but it found it very lacking on this topic.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should see commented out quick reply examples set in the default index.js file in Dialogflow's console.

```
 agent.add(new Suggestion(`Quick Reply`));
 agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion`));
```

You can also see from the [Github repo](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/d8396faab7ebaed4b4aeb7b39dd45f19f8e5c9a3/src/rich-responses/suggestions-response.js) there's other available methods for Quick Replies:

```
let suggestion = new Suggestion('reply to be overwritten');
suggestion.setReply('reply overwritten');
```